# Ruby on rails: thread execution and logging

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, multithreading, activerecord

Suppose I have an User model and when I create a new user model, I spawn a new thread that needs to some networking/background tasks after the user has been created.

```
def create
  @user = User.new(params[:user])

  collect_info_async(@user)

  respond_to do |format|
    if @user.save
      format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User created.' }
    else
      format.html { render action: "new" }
    end
  end
end


def collect_info_async(user)
  Thread.new do
    logger.info "Thread starting" #Gets logged correctly

    #Do some network requests, perform calculations, etc.

    usr = User.find_by_id(user.id).update_attributes(:info => gathered_info)
    logger.info "Thread finishing"


   end
end
```

When I create a new user, then in the logs I see "Thread starting", but I don't see "Thread finishing" at the same moment when it really finishes. I have to do a User.find from the console or refresh the user page after some time and then I am able to see the "Thread finishing" log. So when does the asynchronous task really finish? And is using a Thread the right choice? I'm using Ruby 1.9.3 and Rails 3.2.8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment is it better to use a dedicated worker process for background jobs in Rails, instead if using threads. You could use Sidekiq, Resque, delayed_job, etc. [RailsCasts](http://railscasts.com/) have some good screencasts about those.

There is actually a good [RailsCast about thread-safety](http://railscasts.com/episodes/365-thread-safety). You need to be a pro member to watch it, however.

Comment: Got it working with Sidekiq, thanks. I find it's still odd behaviour, though.